# Rendering elements classname in client-side without JS framework? (EJS)

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

Let's say I have an app which shows to the users a list of existing hobbies.
Each hobby has a category, stored in the db.
I want every hobby element to have its background color - dependent on its category.
I want to implement this with appending specific class to each element.
Basic example code:
**Server**

```
app.get("/hobbies", (req, res) => {
    const hobbies = Hobby.getAllHobbies();  

    res.render("hobbies", hobbies);
});
```

**Client (EJS)**

```
<% hobbies.forEach(hobby => { %>
    <div class=""><%= hobby.name %></div>
<% }); %>
```

What is the best way to append to each div a class depending of hobby.category?

I know its easily possible in React, but I don't want to use any framework for now.

Answer (score 1):

If your classname is not the same as the category but is *based on* it, then you just need to pass a lookup object to your template.

#### Server

```js
const categories_classnames = {
    lookup: {
       swimming: 'div-swim',
       biking: 'div-bike',
       painting: 'div-paint',
       // ...
    }
};

app.get("/hobbies", (req, res) => {
    const hobbies = Hobby.getAllHobbies();

    // Alternatively, `locals = { ...hobbies, ...categories_classnames }`
    const locals = Object.assign({}, hobbies, categories_classnames);

    res.render("hobbies", locals);
});
```

#### Client

```
<% hobbies.forEach(hobby => { %>
    <div class="<%= lookup[hobby.category] %>"><%= hobby.name %></div>
<% }); %>
```

Comment: Good idea, thanks :). Is there a way to have that done without sending any additional data besides the hobbies themselves to the client? @romellem